# Query on field shadowing in java

Tags: java

This concept contradicts the concept of a `class` and it's instance.

Below is the program that looks fine to me and gives `NullPointerException` as expected:

```
class SuperClass{
    int x = 2;
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    int x = 4;
}

public class Dummy2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SubClass obj1 = new SubClass();
        SuperClass obj2 = null;
        System.out.println(obj1.x);
        System.out.println(obj2.x);
    }

}
```

But when I  say  `SuperClass obj2 = obj1;` strangely I see the value of `SuperClass` instance member value `2`,
despite there is no instance of `class SuperClass` created in the above program.

Is this the valid concept in Java?

Comment: How can you access a field of something that doesn't exist (`null`)?

Answer (score 7):

First, since `obj2` is `null` in your example, it will of course throw a NPE when you attempt to access `x` in it.

Second, when you set `obj2 = obj1`, you are casting `obj1`, of type `SubClass`, to type `SuperClass`. When you then access `x` in `obj2`, you are accessing the `x` that `SuperClass` knows about, which has a value of `2`. This is how it is supposed to work.

The reason is, the `x` in `SubClass` isn't overwriting the `x` in `SuperClass`. It is simply hiding it. So when `obj1` is cast to type `SuperClass`, the `x` in `SuperClass` is now the visible `x`.

If you wish to get the `x` value that you seem to be expecting, simply use a getter instead of accessing x directly, and then you can override it in `SubClass`.

SuperClass:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public int x = 2;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

SubClass:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int x = 4;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

test code:

```
SubClass obj1 = new SubClass();
SuperClass obj2 = obj1;

System.out.println(obj2.x);      // outputs 2
System.out.println(obj2.getX()); // outputs 4
```

Comment: Yep. For the OP, emphasis on **It is simply hiding it**, that's the answer in a nutshell.

Comment: i understand that `SubClass` field is shadowing `SuperClass` field.My question is, what is the necessity to provide such language design for "fields" unlike "methods". "overiding" makes more sense for both "methods" and "fields" from language perspective. Because the more strong question always remains that, how can an instance member value get accessed before creating an instance of  `SuperClass`? This is what i mentioned in my first line of query. Number of upvotes seem to indicate that  people are taking it for granted on whatever java provides for free.

Comment: But you did create an instance of `SuperClass`. `SubClass` extends `SuperClass`, therefore `obj1` IS an instance of `SuperClass`, as well as `SubClass`.

Comment: when i say `new SubClass()`, method f() overidden in `SubClass` will be part of this instance, similarly field x(=4) that is suppose to be overridden(ideally) should be available, despite parent type reference point to this instance. Because `x` is an instance member field and it's value should be accessible after i say `new SuperClass()`.

Comment: So you are expecting a variable of type `SuperClass` to have access to a field in `SubClass`? This can't work. What if you also have `SubClass2` which extends `SuperClass`, and also has a field `x`? How will your `SuperClass` variable know which class it actually is (`SubClass` or `SubClass2`), and so know which `x` value to use? A super class knows nothing about its sub classes.

Comment: `SuperClass` variable should know about its subclasses in a same way that it knows methods, if i would like to call "dynamic field look up". another point is, `final int x =2;` in `SuperClass` also works?

Comment: So really, you just want Java to behave differently than it does. Class variables can't be overridden like methods can be. Instead, they are hidden. That is the way Java was designed. If you want to get the x value that you wish, you can create a getter for it in `SuperClass`, and override that in `SubClass`.

Comment: It is not just about Java to behave differently, It is about understanding that, Does it make sense for Java to behave differently? something like similar discussion that we had in my recent [query](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/266334/why-public-access-level-method-get-overridden-in-java).

Comment: I don't know why the people who created Java chose to make it this way, but this is how it is. If you can't accept that, then I suggest you take it up with them.

Comment: Overriding fields makes significantly less sense: fields don't have behavior, they only have values.  If you want to change the value of a field from a superclass, you can just do that in the constructor.  There is a simpler alternative to overriding available to fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid in java, and many other languages *strongly* typed. When you upcast the variable to a superclass you can use properties of that class only. This make a variable strongly typed. Means that you have a variable of the type that you can use regardless of instance type. The type of variable is important that you have access to.